# Getting minimum of attribute of hashes/objects in arrays

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created following syntax for two methods and cant put them together. Further I hope there's a shorter way to write this because it's not really lean:

```
@e = @c_entries.find_all{|i| i.order_no.between?(1,5)}
```

Gives me an array of all objects that's order_no is between 1 and 5!!

```
@f = @c_entries.all(:select => :order_no).collect(&:order_no).min
```

Creates an array of all order_no and gives me the minimum!

What I am trying now is to get the minimum order_no within all objects which order_no is between 1 and 5 as short as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem with combining these two?

Comment: I tried it in the rails console and it gave me a method error. `@e = @c_entries.find_all{|i| i.order_no.between?(1,5)}.all(:select => :order_no).collect(&:order_no).min`.. And its way to long isnt there a shorter way because the controller has to do that for a lot of section. Its used for a huge mapping so I dont want to use too many queries.

Comment: Oh my god. You have no idea what these lines mean, do you?

Comment: Okay got it now with this syntax: `@e = @c_entries.all(:select => :order_no).collect(&:order_no).find_all{|i| i.between?(1,5)}.min` but is there a shorter way?

Comment: Good work! Looks quite compact to me. Just hide it in a method or something.

Comment: I do but probably not well enough :) Theres still a lot I dont really know but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@c_entries` contains a collection of particular model in your application, you can take advantage of ActiveRecord's query interface:

```
@c_entries.where(order_no: 1..5).select(:order_no).min
```

There are various other ways to narrow down your queries: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Comment: Nice, works well. Just have to add `.order_no` to get the order_no back.